# Parsing SOAP XML data using Perl SOAP::Parser Module. Can't install module using CPAN

Tags: xml, perl, soap

Now I have urgent work for parsing SOAP XML data.

I chose `SOAP::Parser` as the best module, then I tried to install it using CPAN but it gives error like `don't know what is this`.

If it is not possible can you give SOAP  XML parser modules?

Answer (score 1):

Have you spelled the module wrongly? CPAN needs the right capitalization and the right number of colons.

Also try just installing just `SOAP` which is the containing module

Comment: Try giving us the complete command and all of its output, not just your condensed version.

Comment: I am writing from my phone and have no CPAN facility on here so can't check. If the OP knows how to install `SOAP::Parser` then I am sure he can try installing `SOAP`. It is either `cpan SOAP` from a shell prompt or `install SOAP` from a CPAN prompt